# CSS - Animation scale with border-radius

Tags: css, animation, transform

I'm working on a animation with scaling a box and it is rounded with 8px. Ref: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ePGxqy. However, the rounded angle is weird when the box expanded and I don't want to scale it by changing its width in keyframes. How can I correctly scale a rounded box with a rounded border?

```css
#box {
  position: relative;
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  background: #aaa;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 8px;
  animation-name: singleRevert;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#box:hover {
  animation-name: singleExpend;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes singleRevert {
  0% {
    transform: scaleX(7.5) scaleY(0.46)
  }
  50% {
    transform: scaleX(1) scaleY(0.46)
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleX(1) scaleY(1)
  }
}

@keyframes singleExpend {
  0% {
    transform: scaleX(1) scaleY(1)
  }
  50% {
    transform: scaleX(1) scaleY(0.46)
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleX(7.5) scaleY(0.46)
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Comment: When you scale an element, it stretches hence give that result. A possible solution would be to also change the radius when scaled/animated, to `border-radius: 1px / 8px;`

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to animate your border radius to match the scale of your box.

For simplicity's sake if your box radius is 8px and you scale your box by 8 times your border radius should be 1px at the scaled size. If your box is 0.5 scaled the border would be 16px;

Alternatively you could animate the width and height of the box. This would respect the borders and you would not have to change them in this case.

Updated your version:

```css
#box {
  position: relative;
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  background: #aaa;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 8px;
  animation-name: singleRevert;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#box:hover {
  animation-name: singleExpend;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes singleRevert {
  0% {
    transform: scaleX(8) scaleY(0.5);
    border-radius: 1px;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scaleX(1) scaleY(0.5)
    border-radius: 8px;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleX(1) scaleY(1)
    border-radius: 8px;
  }
}

@keyframes singleExpend {
  0% {
    transform: scaleX(1) scaleY(1)
    border-radius: 8px;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scaleX(1) scaleY(0.5)
    border-radius: 8px;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleX(8) scaleY(0.5)
    border-radius: 1px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Simple version:

```css
#box {
  position: relative;
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  background: #aaa;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 8px;
  animation-name: singleRevert;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#box:hover {
  animation-name: singleExpend;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes singleRevert {
  0% {
    width: 400px;
    height: 40px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 55px;
    height: 40px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
  }
}
@keyframes singleExpend {
  0% {
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 55px;
    height: 40px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 400px;
    height: 40px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem with animating it by using transform is that you are stretching the element. So whatever border-radius you have it set to, will also get stretched along with the width and height of your element. ScaleX and ScaleY scales the ENTIRE element, not just the dimensions.

A better solution to animating the size of your element while having the border radius be consistent is to animate the height and width. Something like this would work:

```
@keyframes singleExpend {
  0% {
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 55px;
    height: 40px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 400px;
    height: 40px;
  }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Stephen! Is this the only way to scale a rounded element by changing its width? As I read https://medium.com/outsystems-experts/how-to-achieve-60-fps-animations-with-css3-db7b98610108, we better to perform transform scale rather than modifing the width.